# Sort Stylus content

Tags: html, css, sorting, coding-style, stylus

Is there a way to sort lines in Stylus files by some criteria, e.g. alphabetically, or by rules domain, like, all background things are put one after another, then all positioning things, like `top`, `right` and so on?
Surely, these lines should stay inside their parent element.
Here is an example:

```
#topbar
    clearfix()
    position fixed
    height topBarHeight
    border-bottom 1px solid rgba(#fff, 0.2)
    box-sizing border-box
    z-index 200
    right 0
    left 0
```

Can become this, grouped by domain:

```
#topbar
    // mixins
    clearfix()
    // positioning and sizing
    position fixed
    z-index 200
    left 0
    right 0
    box-sizing border-box
    height topBarHeight
    // border
    border-bottom 1px solid rgba(#fff, 0.2)
    // the rest
    ...
```

It's a kind of a perfectionist itch, but would be cool to have all files content in some order.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a script for a scriptable text editor like vim if you want the lines to be sorted in the stylus source file. If you want the output to be optimised, there are some postcss-plugins available. You may want to take a look at
[postcss-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-sort) and
[postcss-merge-rules](https://github.com/ben-eb/postcss-merge-rules). You will find more if you use the keyword 'merge'.